# Switch case in Ruby , making else to return data in a Break event

Tags: ruby

I currently learning ruby. I tried a small piece of code which will return the country based on the city

Code:

```
message = nil
flag = true
while true
    print "Enter city name : "

    city_name = gets.chomp
    message = case city_name

        when "Frankfurt" then "It is in germany"
            
        when "Paris" then "It is in France"
            
        else "Not present in memeory!!!"
            break

        end

    puts "Message is : #{message}"
end

puts "Out of the loop"
```

How ever when I type any other value other than frankfurt and paris, I only get "`out of loop`" printed and not "`Not present in memory`"

Based on my understanding the string given after '`then`' command is being returned to the variable '`message`'. Why is that the string given after else is not being returned to the variable ?
When I try it without the `break` statement it seems to work fine.

Comment: break interrupts the whole loop, spo puts is not reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for [`break`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement) explain that it's used to *"leave a block early"* and in particular to *"terminate from a while loop"*.

In your code, that block is

```
while true
  # ...
end
```

When calling `break`, the block is left right-away and execution continues after `end`.

As you already figured out, the fix is to remove `break` if you don't want to break out of the loop. Also, if there is no condition, you can use [`loop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#loop-method) instead of `while true`.

You might want to designate another value to break the loop explicitly, e.g. by checking for [`empty?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#empty-3F-method) string:

```
loop do
  print "Enter city name: "

  city_name = gets.chomp
  break if city_name.empty?

  message = case city_name
            when "Frankfurt"
              "It is in Germany"
            when "Paris"
              "It is in France"
            else
              "Not present in memory!!!"
            end

  puts "Message is: #{message}"
end

puts "Out of the loop"
```

Example:

```
Enter city name: Frankfurt↵
Message is: It is in Germany
Enter city name: Paris↵
Message is: It is in France
Enter city name: London↵
Message is: Not present in memory!!!
Enter city name: ↵
Out of the loop
```